# Atlasian api - user two factor verification

Tags: jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to get a user's two factor authentication status (enforced,active,disabled,...) via any one of their api's.

I have read the documentation from here and could not find a thing:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-user-properties/#api-group-user-properties
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/intro/
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/admin/user-management/rest/intro/

with no such option found. doe's anyone have an idea?